# Realtime database emulator ignores database.rules.json

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-cli

I have a Firebase project that uses the realtime database, and I'm trying to set up the local emulator for testing. Unfortunately, it seems that the Firebase-cli is ingoring my `database.rules.json` file. This happens even after creating a test project to solve this specific problem.

Let me give you some info about my setup.

I created a Firebase project with nothing enabled. I created an empty directory on my local machine and ran `firebase init database`. Doing that created a few files:

`.firebaserc`

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "emulators-test-244be"
  }
}
```

`firebase.json`

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  }
}
```

`database.rules.json` (I modified the rules here to lock down the database)

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

When I run the emulator using `firebase emulators:start --only database`, the console tells me that the database successfully initializes. However, when I visit `http://localhost:9000/.inspect/coverage?ns=emulators-test-244be` to view the currently loaded security rules, it gives the following output:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

Obviously, this directly contradicts the rules I have set in the `database.rules.json` file.

One thing I did notice, is that if I modify the `database.rules.json` file while the emulator is running, I get the following output from the console:

`i  database: Change detected, updating rules for undefined...`

Apparently, doing this causes the emulator to create a new database called `undefined`. When I go to `http://localhost:9000/.inspect/coverage?ns=undefined`, the output correctly reflects what I have set in my `database.rules.json` file.

Why is this happening? Am I incorrectly setting up my local Firebase project? Or is there a bug in the Firebase CLI? I've scoured the Firebase docs, Stack Overflow, and Google. I haven't found anything.

I have firebase tools version `8.4.3`.

**UPDATE**

After searching through the issues on the `firebase-tools` GitHub repo, it seems that this is a bug.

Link here: 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2371

Comment: I had a similar issue today, my rules weren't being loaded. I noticed in my realtime database emulator console there were four different databases online: `myprojectid`, `emulatorui`, `fake-server`, `myprojectid-default-rtdb`. I don't know why, but the emulator was loading my project rules just for the last one. The solution was to change `databaseURL` in my firebase config to `http://localhost:9000?ns=vttrpg-db43b-default-rtdb`. I still don't know where is the configuration for the other three instances.

Answer (score 4):

This workaround worked for me:

`.firebaserc`

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "emulators-test-244be"
  },
  "targets": {
    "emulators-test-244be": {
      "database": {
        "default": [
          "emulators-test-244be"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`firebase.json`

```
{
  "database": [
    {
      "target": "default",
      "rules": "database.rules.json"
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 4000
    }
  }
}
```

When I start the emulator with `firebase emulators:start` and visit: `http://localhost:9000/.inspect/coverage?ns=emulators-test-244be` I get the rules specified in my `database.rules.json` file.

Hope it also works for others with this problem.